# Halcon - Create hom_mat3D from data / Ajust existing hom_mat3D data

Tags: matrix, 3d, halcon, homogenous-transformation

I am trying to create a Halcon homogeneous transformation matrix with data aquired from another process. I will be using it to generate a pose, which in turn will be used for rigid transformation.

The most useful option for hom_mat3D creation I have found so far is:
`hom_mat3d_identity (HomMat3DIdentity)`

I tried using `create_matrix` and `set_value_matrix` to fill a matrix with the known data and then use `hom_mat2d_compose(HomMat3DIdentity, matrix, result)` Unfortunately Matrix and Hom_mat3d don't mix.

In short: How do I create a Halcon homogeneous transformation matrix from previously acuired variables?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet that shows how to create a hom_mat3d as well as a pose, write new data inside them and then multiply them together.

```
hom_mat3d_identity (HomMat3DIdentity)
HomMat3DIdentity[0] := 11
HomMat3DIdentity[1] := 2
HomMat3DIdentity[2] := 6
HomMat3DIdentity[3] := 45
HomMat3DIdentity[4] := 22
HomMat3DIdentity[5] := 88
HomMat3DIdentity[6] := 25
HomMat3DIdentity[7] := 9
HomMat3DIdentity[8] := 12
HomMat3DIdentity[9] := 106
HomMat3DIdentity[10] := 23
HomMat3DIdentity[11] := 48

hom_mat3d_to_pose (HomMat3DIdentity, Pose1)

create_pose (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 90, 90, 90, 'Rp+T', 'gba', 'point', Pose2)
Pose2[0] := 67
Pose2[1] := 71
Pose2[2] := 11
Pose2[3] := 23
Pose2[4] := 56
Pose2[5] := 98

pose_compose (Pose1, Pose2, Pose3)
```

Comment: Array notation! and in Halcon a homMat3D is an array of 12 not a matrix of 16.